# showing PDF content in Zend or PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I want to show the content of a PDF file in a div.
Anyone can tell how to do it in Zend or PHP?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert PDF to an JPG/PNG image so you can display it on HTML page? You can embed PDF file directly using iframe, but it will depend on your user's browser if it will be displayed correctly.

Comment: no, I don't want to convert pdf file to any image format. How can I use iframe for this purpose?

Comment: You maybe will be interested in FlexPaper http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

Comment: I don't want to use any plugin.. @BogdanBurim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div>
<object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
</object>
</div>
```

Reference From : http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?152923-PDF-within-a-DIV

Comment: Is it necessary that my browser must have a pdf plugin to show the content?

Comment: @AdityaVijay Yes, since PDF can't be natively displayed in a browser, or within an HTML element, they need a plugin.